# Auto-layout: What creates constraints named UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width & Height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

My layout constraints are fine in Interface Builder but an exception occurs at runtime thanks to some part of the framework applying fixed height and width constraints that I really don't want. Why are they there, and how to turn them off?

They're the last two constraints shown in the logged list:

```
2014-04-26 09:02:58.687 BBCNews[32058:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xbf478a0 UIView:0xbf4a3c0.height == 0.28125*UIView:0xbf4a3c0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xbf47190 UIView:0xbf4a3c0.leading == BNMyNewsCell_landscape:0xbf48b10.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xbf47160 UIView:0xbf4a3c0.trailing == BNMyNewsCell_landscape:0xbf48b10.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xbf47130 BNMyNewsCell_landscape:0xbf48b10.bottom == UIView:0xbf4a3c0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xbf47100 UIView:0xbf4a3c0.top == BNMyNewsCell_landscape:0xbf48b10.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd4c3c40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[BNMyNewsCell_landscape:0xbf48b10(304)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd4c38a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[BNMyNewsCell_landscape:0xbf48b10(290)]>"
}
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

<NSLayoutConstraint:0xbf478a0 UIView:0xbf4a3c0.height == 0.28125*UIView:0xbf4a3c0.width>
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Based on a ton of observation I believe (but cannot know for certain) that the constraints named `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` and `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` are created by `UICollectionView` and friends, and exist to enforce the size returned by the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method. I guess it's there to ensure that the `UICollectionViewCell` set up by `cellForItemAtIndexPath` ends up the size that it was told it would be.

Which answers my initial question here. A second question is why were the constraints unsatisfiable? The cell's intrinsic height should have been the same as `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height`. Again, I don't know for certain, but I suspect it was a rounding error (i.e. intrinsic height came to 200.1 pixels, the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` maybe rounded to 200. The fix I came up with was to just lower the priority of the relevant cell constraint to allow `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` to have the last word.

Comment: Are you resizing any cells just before you get this warning? I have a feeling that UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height is the calculated height for cell.

Comment: This fixed my constraint breakage and corresponding warning messages, but now my text view is collapsed until I scroll the cell out of view and then back in.

Comment: @Alex311 did you try adjusting the Compression Resistance (or whatever it's called) in IB? I've found that increasing this value helps prevent text collapsing

Comment: Started to happen for me when running on iOS8.  Was programmatically setting constraints on a view used for a section header.  Fixed my issue by setting bounds on the content (container) view, where the width and height were more representative of what they needed to be, ( 320, 44 ), rather than being ( 0, 0 )

Comment: just to add to this, I had similar issue with `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` in 8.3 device and remembered about [this tweet](https://twitter.com/sanjeetsuhag/status/586039564537475072/photo/1). Calling `[someView layoutIfNeeded]` helped resolve the issue.

Comment: I had totally left hope of fixing constraint warnings in console but somehow I encountered another constraint issue which lead me to this page and I was glad to land here and see your answer. I just lowered the priority to 999 and boom, all my constraint warnings were gone :) Thank you so much :) :) :)

Answer (score 48):

This may not answer your question, but it could help others like me who got here from search.

I was getting a strange AutoLayout broken constraint error accompanied by a `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` constraint because I was adding a `tableHeaderView` to a table view that hadn't been sized with AutoLayout yet. So the system was trying to apply my header subviews' constraints inside a tableview with a frame of `{0,0,0,0}`. Since UITableView likes control over the width of its elements, its generated width constraint, `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width`, was set to zero, causing all kinds of confusion with my header elements that were expecting 320+pt width.

The takeaway: make sure you are adding/manipulating your supplementary/header/footer views after the tableview has been sized by AutoLayout.

Comment: I want to be sure I am doing this correctly. Can you explain how to be certain these manipulations occur after AutoLayout?

Comment: @nwales The problem arises when iOS tries to layout constraints inside of a 0 by 0 view. To avoid this error, just make sure the container view (in my case, the tableHeaderView) is either laid out or manually sized. You can do this by initializing the container view with an approximate size before setting constraints, or if you want pure Autolayout- lay out the container view's constraints then call `[thatContainer layoutIfNeeded]` before setting the subview constraints. If you're not getting the error and your views are straight, then you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks! Flipping the order in which I layouted my table view and assigned its header made this error disappear =)

Comment: The best solution for this is to drop the priorities of your constraints so they are not required. Dropping priority to high works.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same weird constraint and had no idea why, until I remembered the darned `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property. Setting this to `false` solved the problem.
What happens in the background is that the auto resizing masks (the old layout engine for iOS) are converted to constraints. Very often you don't want these constraints and want your own ones. In such cases you should set this property to false and you'll be fine:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: Which `view` are you setting this on exactly? Is it UITableViewCell?

Comment: You usually set it on the view that you're about to add.

Answer (score 6):

After banging my head for a while i found [this link](https://aplus.rs/2017/one-solution-for-90pct-auto-layout). In my case it was happening on the UITableViewHeaderFooterView when i was using insertRows or deleteRows from my UIVieController. 'estimatedSectionHeaderHeight' and 'estimatedRowHeight' where set, my constraints redone 3 times ... The error shown was:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280648140 H:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x106e94860]   (active, names: '|':DAT_Air_Vinyl.ExportsAlbumTableViewHeader:0x106e8fb50 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280648230 H:[UIImageView:0x106e94860]-(8)-[DAT_Air_Vinyl.MainLabel:0x106ea5750'The Coral - The Invisible...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280648410 H:[UIButton:0x106ea5a40]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':DAT_Air_Vinyl.ExportsAlbumTableViewHeader:0x106e8fb50 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280648460 H:[DAT_Air_Vinyl.MainLabel:0x106ea5750'The Coral - The Invisible...']-(8)-[UIButton:0x106ea5a40]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2806493b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' DAT_Air_Vinyl.ExportsAlbumTableViewHeader:0x106e8fb50.width == 0   (active)>"
```

As stated on the link:

"**When you do insertRows or deleteRows with certain animation types, UIKit will animate the row height from 0 to full height or back. At the 0-end of that animation, the layout equations are impossible to solve if entire vertical axis is set to priority=1000. But lower just one constraint to 999 – say that bottom space to superview margin – and all is fine; the content will just drop-down, outside the cell’s bounds.**".

The solution was to set to 999 (or lower to 1000) the leading priority of the UIImageView.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely seeing this on a `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView`. I was able to get this to work with a custom header view by explicitly setting the width equal to that of the `tableView` after setting the `tableHeaderView`, THEN resetting it after a layout pass has completed.

Example code for iOS 9, which assumes you have a `UITableView` passed into your method as `tableView` and an item to configure it as `item`:

```
//Create the header view
self.contentDetailHeaderView = MyCustomHeaderView()

//Turn on autolayout
self.contentDetailHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

//Add the header to the table view
tableView.tableHeaderView = self.contentDetailHeaderView

//Pin the width  
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentDetailHeaderView,
    attribute: .Width,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: tableView,
    attribute: .Width,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0)

tableView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

//Do whatever configuration you need to - this is just a convenience method I wrote on my header view.
self.contentDetailHeaderView.setupForItem(item)

//Lay out the configured view
self.contentDetailHeaderView.layoutIfNeeded()

//Reset the table header view, because ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
tableView.tableHeaderView = self.contentDetailHeaderView
```

Couple of notes, mostly for when I look this up again because I have the memory of a goldfish:

- You do *not* have to call this from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - I was able to use this technique as long as the `tableView` has the appropriate width during setup.
- You do need to make sure your header view is set up to automatically resize itself. I did this by creating a `.xib`  and then making sure all items were pinned so that as the view changed width, the height would then update.
- If you're trying to do this for `viewForHeaderInSection`, you're probably better off grabbing something offscreen which you can lay out a la [this technique](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html). I haven't had much luck with the self-sizing bits.

Comment: Wow. After half an hour of messing around... this actually works! I don't understand why it is needed, but it works. Pretty crappy that we have to do it this way though.

Answer (score 4):

We've started seeing tons of layout conflicts in iOS 11 that include references to these constraints and they are in fact added via the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` flag.  It seems that in iOS 11 there's a lot more AutoLayout magic happening when a view is added to the hierarchy rather than just when the view is laid out (as it seemed to work in previous iOS versions).

This is the case that we were running into:

- Create a view whose internal layout helps define the views size (e.g., the view has internal constraints that includes explicit padding, etc.)
- *** Add this view to the hierarchy.
- Set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false some time later, before the layout pass.

The second step (***) will result in a conflict because the system will add zero size constraints to the view at the time the view is added to the hierarchy.  We were setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` later as a result of using the PureLayout framework which automatically sets this flag correctly when you constrain the view...  That said, in iOS 11 you need to remember to turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` at construction time, before the view is added to the hierarchy.

I suspect Apple thought that defaulting this flag to YES would be way more helpful than it is painful.  Unfortunately, this has not been the case.

Comment: PureLayout provides ```initForAutoLayout``` and ```newAutoLayoutView``` initialisers that set ```translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints``` to false which can be called on ALView subclasses

Answer (score 3):

I got this error in all sorts of circumstances (not necessarily tied to UICollectionView and friends as suggested by the [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23910943/766570) answer here)..

So my way of dealing with it was simply clearing all the constraints then building them again (only this time i have no fear of my constraints colliding with these pre-created ones):

so in code:

```
UIView *parentView = [viewInQuestion superview];
[parentView clearConstraintsOfSubview:viewInQuestion];
```

where `clearConstraintsOfSubview` is a category method on UIView:

```
- (void)clearConstraintsOfSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in [self constraints]) {
        if ([[constraint firstItem] isEqual:subview] || [[constraint secondItem] isEqual:subview]) {
            [self removeConstraint:constraint];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue and solved it with the following.

- **Environment:** Swift 5.0, xcode 10.2.1, Setting views programmatically
- **Warning message:** Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints... 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x0000000000.width == 0   (active)>"
  )
- **Code with warning**

  ```
  override func loadView() {

  view = UIView()

  /// Adds the subviews to the view and sets their properties and constraints
  setupViews()

  }
  ```
- **Code that cleared warning**

  ```
  override func loadView() {

  /// Needed to set the frame of the root view to the window frame.
  let window = UIWindow()
  view = UIView(frame: window.frame)

  /// Adds the subviews to the view and sets their properties and constraints
  setupViews()
  }
  ```
- **Notes on the loadView() method:** "If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method. You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super." - Apple documentation
- **Notes on the root view:**

  "If you prefer to create views programmatically ... you do so by overriding 
  your view controller’s loadView method. Your implementation of this method 
  should do the following:

  Create a root view object. The root view contains all other views associated 
  with your view controller. You typically define the frame for this view to 
  match the size of the app window, which itself should fill the screen. However, 
  the frame is adjusted based on how your view controller is displayed. See “View 
  Controller View Resizing.”

  You can use a generic UIView object, a custom view you define, or any other 
  view that can scale to fill the screen.

  Create additional subviews and add them to the root view." - Old apple 
  documentation?

Answer (score 2):

`UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-*` are the constraints used by table, collection, and stacks to layout elements as you told them to do it. If you later set constraints that create a change in size you’ll get a conflict. An example of this use case is cells that download images with variable size.

This happens because we are used to layoutIfNeeded() to refresh the layout, but once a collection goes through the rendering cycle the cell size is set with encapsulated constraints. You need to manually invalidate the index path you need to refresh, e.g.

```
let context = UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext()
context.invalidateItems(at: [cellIndexPath])
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)
```

this will recursively create more invalidations to shift the positions of other cells and make space.

If you set, e.g. a different height constraint to change the size of the cell it will instantly crash and then recover after you invalidate and the cell is layout again. To avoid this crash you can lower the priority of the height constraint below `.required`, for instance UILayoutPriority(999).

Comment: Example: https://github.com/janodev/SelfSizingCollection

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was inadvertently setting up my programmatic constraints twice. As soon as I removed the duplicate call, the conflicts went away.

Answer (score 1):

I catch this problem when I use AL create tableviewHeader

I init tableview like below

```
let table = UITableView.init(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
// set table constraint ...
```

then I create tableviewHeader with AutoLayout.

`"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d7d130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fe92bc55260.width == 0   (active)>"`

symbolic breakpoint appear

After I refer @Yerk 's the answer.
I change the frame when I init tableView

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 0)
let table = UITableView.init(frame:rect , style: .grouped)
```

The problem seems to be solved

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution for CollectionView! If You using storyBoard, like I am, it will help you!

**Interface Builder / Storyboard**

Go to ***storyBoard*** -> chose your ***CollectionView***
[ScreenShot CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgWTc.png)
Go to Size Inspector
Then set ***Estimate Size*** to ***None***
[ScreenShot Estimate Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1rnH.png)

Thats All!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem found from testing Split View on the iPad Pro, and DesignatedNerd's answer worked but I didn't need so much code. Here is what I used:

```
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myTableHeaderView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self.tableView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  multiplier:1
                                                                    constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *yConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myTableHeaderView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.tableView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1
                                                                constant:0];


[self.tableView addConstraints:@[widthConstraint, yConstraint]];
```

Note the addition of the Y Constraint, which binds the top of the tableHeaderView to the top of the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when adding constraints to a Table view header. It seem to occur when adding constraints with set constants when the bounds of the header was (0,0,0,0). I managed to fix this by only adding the constraints in the layout subviews method when the bounds of the header was not (0,0,0,0)

```
    if self.bounds == CGRect.zero {
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

constraint `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` is created with value you set in `tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight`