# Swift UITableViewCell separatorStyle breaking autolayout on iPhone MIni

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, cornerradius

I have a UITableView which has a UITableViewCell which contains a UIImageView.

The constraints are setup such that the UIImageView has padding 20 points at the top and sides, and a size ratio of 1:1, so the UIImageView will always be square regardless of the device width.

I apply a cornerRadius to the UIImageView so the image is circular.

However.... the autolayout doesn't seem to work on the first load.  But after the first load, it works perfectly.

I have tried every known combination of setNeedsLayout or layoutIfNeeded - both inside the UITableViewCell and in the UITableView code.  Nothing works the first time it loads.

Please help!

Code looks like this:

```
class CircularProfileCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var circularView: UIView!
    
    func setup() {
        circularView.layer.cornerRadius = circularView.bounds.height / 2
    }
}

class CircularProfileVC: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CircularProfileCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CircularProfileCell")
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CircularProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! CircularProfileCell
        cell.setup()
        return cell
    }
}
```

Setup looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you explain how you set cornerRadius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only happens when the `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`

So to fix it I simply leave the separator on, but set the separator color to clear

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
```

Thanks to @CloudBalacing for the help. More info about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172250/uitableview-auto-resizing-row-constraint-breaking-mysteriously-on-iphone-6plus)

Answer (score 0):

Because corner radius is a `layer` property it does not always play well with auto layout. In addition, I guess you set it up with frame properties of the view (i.e `imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.height/2`).
Hence you should try and set the corner radius on the `layoutSubviews()` function of the cell. This will make sure to render the correct size

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.height/2
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cloudbalancing.  This doesn't seem to do it unfortunately.  The code is called but it still fails to render correctly.

Comment: hmmm, can you share the code?

Comment: Also if you can add the configuration of the size (autolayout or frames) of the view it self it would be helpful

Comment: All added above - thank you so much for helping with this @CloudBalancing

Comment: I've narrowed it down to a problem with the separatorStyle on the tableView.  Because I set it to .none, the layout breaks.  Investigating now.