# How to set the height of UISegmentedControl subclass without using auto layout?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created a `UISegmentedControl` subclass that I would like to use as the section header view for a `UITableView`.

I would like the custom `UISegmentedControl` subclass to have a height of 50pt.

I am aware that I can create a height constraint for this. However, after setting the height constraint, if this segmented control is used as the section header of the table view, then auto layout errors are shown ( see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308400/auto-layout-what-creates-constraints-named-uiview-encapsulated-layout-width-h/43070239) ).

I tried setting height by calling the init(frame:) method with appropriate height, but this has no effect.

Is there a way to set the height of the `UISegmentedControl` subclass without using auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `frames` to set the `size` and `position` of `UISegmentedControl` inside a `sectionHeaderView`, i.e.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 50))
    segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "First", at: 0, animated: false)
    segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Second", at: 1, animated: false)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]